# how to display the table using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to reactjs and Im just trying to create a page with the userName and password. When the `submit` is clicked it should display a list of table names in the same page. For this I have two react components, placed it in a separate js file. So when the button is clicked the table names should be generated. I have tried a sample code but I'm unable to display the list. So looking for help in reactjs.

tableContent.js

```
    import React from 'react';

class tableContent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <select name="sometext" multiple="multiple">
                <option>Table1</option>
                <option>Table2</option>
                <option>Table3</option>
                <option>Table4</option>
                <option>Table5</option>
            </select>

        )
    }
}

export default tableContent;
```

login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import tableContent from './tables';
class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            showComponent : false,
        };
        this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
    }

    buttonClick(){
        this.setState({
            showComponent: true,
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label>userName :</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br/>
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}> Submit </button>
                  </form>
                  <tableContent />
            </div>  
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Name `tableContent` to `TableContent`, because name of the react component must start will **upper case letter** otherwise it will be treated as `html` element.

Use `e.preventDefault();` inside `buttonClick` function to prevent the form submission automatically.

Check the working code:

```js
class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            showComponent : false,
        };
    }

    buttonClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            showComponent: true,
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label>userName :</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br/>
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}> Submit </button>
                  </form>
                  {this.state.showComponent && <TableContent />}
            </div>  
        )
    }
}
class TableContent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <select name="sometext" multiple="multiple">
                <option>Table1</option>
                <option>Table2</option>
                <option>Table3</option>
                <option>Table4</option>
                <option>Table5</option>
            </select>

        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Login/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id ='app'/>
```

Comment: check the updated answer, you need to use conditional rendering for that like this: `{this.state.showComponent && <TableContent />}` it will work :)

Comment: @MayankShukla what does this `{this.state.showComponent && <TableContent />}` in reactjs